# Variational Bayes vs EP and other message-passing methods

Tags: bayesian, markov-process

I am trying to understand the difference between:

- [Expectation Propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_propagation) (EP)
- [Variational Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_methods)

Wikipedia says:

> Expectation Propagation differs from other Bayesian approximation approaches such as
>   Variational Bayesian methods.

Why isn't **EP** considered a **Variational Bayes** method? Isn't EP Bayesian, and relies on message-passing to approximate the posterior? What makes a method Variational Bayes?

Also, what about the following methods. Can they be considered Variational Bayes?

- Sum-product
- Mean-field methods
- Bethe-Kikuchi approximations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me VB just means we will approximate posterior by turning the problem into a minimization problem and then changing the solution space. In that sense, EP is a type of VB algorithm, because it does exactly that. When I think of VB, though, the first thing I think of is mean-field, and if I had to guess I would think that whoever wrote that EP is "different" from VB might have had mean-field algorithms in mind.

[This source](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf), which I take to be canonical, explicitly classifies all algorithms you mention as VB (i.e. Bethe-Kikuchi, sum-product, EP, and mean-field).